# ANDROID ERROR Program type already present: com.google.ads.AdRequest$Gender?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, googleads-mobile-unity

I opened my old working app in the new updated stable android studio, I got the following error when select run the app option

**Program type already present: `com.google.ads.AdRequest$Gender`**

```
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.ads.AdRequest$Gender, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I only changes to **build.gradle** file compile to implementation word

```
  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, my bad. That error came because in lib folder also present google ads old jar file and added google ads in gradle too.

Just remove the following line and solved.

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```